# How to catch ssh enabled or not using Shell script for cisco switches?

Tags: cisco, switch, shell-scripting

I have a file of FQDN and I know how to check the ssh. I am using the following command:

```
show ip ssh
```

But I cannot do this manually, so I've decided to write a shell script. But I do not understand how I can check whether ssh is enabled or not using an if and for loop and the above command.

I want to write the FQDN into a file if ssh is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check whether SSH is activated *before* connecting to the switch? Just try it then.

From a Windows client, you can use PuTTY's `plink` for scripting, in Linux you`d use`ssh`.